# Cassandra virtualbox error no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: cassandra, virtualbox

I have cassandra install on the virtualbox and connect to c# application with the address, datacenter name correctly but still get the error. Is there anything that I miss and neede to be checked?
[image]

```
    public ISession session;
    private string IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private string Datacenter = "datacenter1";
    public ISession getConnect()
    {
        return session = Cluster.Builder()
                             .AddContactPoints(IP)
                             .WithPort(9042)
                             .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(Datacenter))
                             .Build()
                             .Connect();
    }
```

Comment: what is the the error code/message error returned ? are you trying connect inside virtual box or outside ?

Comment: I tried connect it from the application on main machine, outside virtualbox. The error is Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 'All hosts tried for query failed (tried 127.0.0.1:9042: SocketException 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')'

Comment: in main machine the localhost (127.0.0.1) don't have Cassandra listening here, only inside virtual box you can access to it. you need to use another IP-Addr in virtualbox that is visible/accessible in main machine, not use the localhost 127.0.0.1.

Comment: the result address after checking telnet connection is the same 127.0.0.1:9042 instead of 10.x.x.x:9042. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Check in virtualbox where Cassandra is listening: netstat -tlnp | grep 9042

try establish a connection using telnet: telnet <ip-addr> 9042

more detail here:
https://community.datastax.com/questions/9242/native-transport-port-open-or-not.html